# Unable to insert into sql server in windows authentication

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

```
private DateTime currentDate;
private string strInsert;
private SqlCommand sqlCmd;
private SqlConnection hookUp;

protected void EnterData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    hookUp = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-BDL7T9A;Database=Vote;" 
                      +  "Integrated Security=True;");        

    strInsert = " INSERT INTO Supporters (LastName,FirstName,";
    strInsert += "E-mail,Donation,DateLastContact)VALUES";
    strInsert += "(@LName,@FName,@Em,@Donate,@NowDate)";

    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strInsert, hookUp);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName",LName.Text);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName",FName.Text);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Em",Em.Text);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Donate",Donate.Text);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NowDate",currentDate);

    hookUp.Open();
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    hookUp.Close();

    Lbl1.Text = "Data has been sent";
}
```

I tried in windows authentication mode. When I run this code with sqlDatabase server it displays error when I try to submit:

> Incorrect syntax near '-'

when I run this program and input the data at the time of database connection it displays same error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use square brackets (delimited identifier) for field names with `-`:

```
strInsert += "[E-mail],Donation,DateLastContact)VALUES";
```

Further reading: MSDN [Database Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You can find there rules for regular identifiers:

> 4. Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.

When identifiers are used in Transact-SQL statements, the identifiers that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets.

Note also that you can use *verbatim string* to span string literal for several lines of code:

```
  strInsert = @"INSERT INTO Supporters 
               (LastName,FirstName,[E-mail],Donation,DateLastContact)
               VALUES (@LName,@FName,@Em,@Donate,@NowDate)";
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help you made my code run I had almost gave up coding but you solved my problem.